# Angular : Facing issues when compared previous reactive form value with current value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a from called verification form and a form array called RepDetails with two fields. By default the form shows two fields. User can add more details by clicking on add more. I want to compare current phonecode[0](for eg: 91),phone number[0](for eg: 8885589897) with phonecode[1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bnwcb3?file=src/app/app.component.ts),phone number[1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bnwcb3?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Which i'm able to do but facing issue on certain scenario. i.e

when I give phonecode[0]=91,phonenumber[0]=123 and again enter phonecode[1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bnwcb3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)=91,phonenumber[1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bnwcb3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)=123 i get error and now if change phoneCode[1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bnwcb3?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to 355 then error goes away which is expected and working fine till now. But then if I click on add more and again select phonecode[2]=91 then phonenumber[1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bnwcb3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)=123 is marked error even though the phoneCode[1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bnwcb3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)=355. Can anyone advise?

you can see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bnwcb3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: You only want it to validate to the previous line?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would only evaluate the previous line for the repeat error.

```
if (
            this.phoneCode &&
            ((formArray.at(i) as FormGroup).get("phoneNumber").value ==
              control.value &&
              i == formArray.controls.length - 2
            )
          )
```